# Can I save a generated by prawn pdf file to the profect folder, using initialize method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I have an `OrderPdf` class that inherits from `Prawn::Document` Here is the content of the class:

```
class OrderPdf < Prawn::Document
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper

  def initialize(order)
    super(top_margin: 50, size: 12)
    @order = order
    logo
    # Other methods that generate pdf's content
    footer
  end

  def logo
    # Some stuff here
  end

  def footer
    #Some stuff here
  end
end
```

I call it like this: `OrderPdf.new(@order)`. Pdf file is generated, but what I need - is to save it into my project with the name, something like this: `"#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/orders/order-#{order.order_number}.pdf"` I know, that I can do this: `Prawn::Document.generate("#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/orders/order-#{order.order_number}.pdf")`, but can I do something simialar with the existing code? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `render_file` method in the initializer.

```
def initialize(order)
  super(top_margin: 50, size: 12)
  @order = order
  logo
  # Other methods that generate pdf's content
  footer
  render_file "#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/orders/order-#{order.order_number}.pdf"
end
```